# Publishing an MVC application to a subfolder of an existing web forms application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I built an MVC web app that needs to be integrated with an existing web application. Unfortunately the existing site is a web forms application.

I would like to publish my MVC app to a sub-directory such as http://www.webforms.com/mvc. The website would ideally be running web forms everywhere until it hits that 'mvc' sub directory (or goes any deeper) in which case it would switch to the MVC configuration.

Another thing to note, is the user logs in in the web forms side, and the login should carry over to the mvc side.

I've done a bit of research, but most articles I've read are for earlier .NET frameworks. Just wondering if anyone has a good solution to this, preferably without needing to modify the old webforms code. Hopefully something that can be achieved mostly through IIS. Please let me know your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think two things are important: set up the routes correctly (do not forget to append to the pattern the subdir name) and to run the application in an integrated mode application pool. (You can create any application whithin another in the IIS management console.)